# Keeping One Split Container Panel Fixed Width?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't seem to figure out how to keep a panel's width fixed in a Split Container in a WinForm.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you want the width to be fixed then why use a split container? You could use two panels.  Or probably better off to use the anchor properties of each of the controls.

Comment: Split containers are design specifically to have liquid panels?  
doh!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd keep one panel's size fixed, there is no logical way to move the splitter.  Since you can't move the splitter, it just doesn't make sense to use a SplitContainer anymore.  Use two Panel controls.

Comment: Or a TableLayoutPanel might be better suited instead of the 2 separate and virtually independent panels.

Comment: thanks for leading in the right direction, it really doesn't make sense to have splicontainer in this case :)

Comment: I disagree.  Take for example the case where I have embedded split containers.  I have 3 segments, 2 of which I want to be resizeable (think 3 columns - a left data column, a right data column, and a tool button column in the middle with fixed width).  So, if I just use 1 split container, I can't put a panel in the right-hand-side, and dock a Listbox control.  The Listbox ends up behind the panel and partially obscured.

Answer (score 107):

property `SplitterPanel.FixedPanel` - set one of the panels to fixed size

property `SplitterPanel.IsSplitterFixed` - set to true

Comment: Note that when the overall size of the SplitContainer becomes too small, the fixed panel will be shrunk to fit, and WON'T grow back to the "fixed" size unless you take care of this in a SizeChanged event...

Comment: won't min. panel size prevent this problem?

Answer (score 14):

In order to make `panel1` fixed
In the properties of the `SplitContainer`, set the `FixedPanel` property to `Panel1`.

Then, set the `SplitDistance` and `Panel1MinSize` to the same value.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  One correction, the property is `SplitterDistance` and not SplitDistance.  In addition, I had to modify the code behind the form, because the properties were not accessible in the Properties window in the IDE, nor through code in the Form events (e.g. Form Load).

Answer (score 12):

Fix Panel (Lock Panel):

```
SplitContainer.FixedPanel = FixedPanel.Panel
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you want.

`FixedPanel` let's the user resize the panel but it won't resize automatically when the control is resized.

`IsSplitterFixed` will disable the splitter, but it will still resize automatically when the control is resized.

If you use both then it will be totaly fixed. But then you're better off using two panels like Hans said.

Answer (score 1):

```
// from Microsoft documentation similar to Dmitri answer:::::::::::
// if make panel1 fixed:
mySplitContainer.FixPanel = System.Windows.Forms.FixedPanel.Panel1;

// if make panel2 fixed (in this case can't use fixed splitter distance):
mySplitContainer.FixPanel = System.Windows.Forms.FixedPanel.Panel2;

// and to be safe set the appropriate panel min size for the splitcontainer too;
```